# Dynamic create translations file. Angular translation

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm in need of a way to dynamically create my translations file for my app.

Right now i can create the json object like this, in my app

```
{
    Name: 'User Name',
}
```

but i can't find a way to tell my $translateProvider to use this to translate my site, Do anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Use angular-gettext translator https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/

Comment: Wow. this work. Thanks you. throw a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use angular-gettext translator

[angular-gettext.rocketeer.be](http://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be)